# The name order in Reference is inverting in Latex

Tags: cross-referencing, natbib

I am using the Elsevier Templates named "`els-cas-templates`".
The article that I am ready to submit need the reference is ordered by the first name of author and year.

Now I have a bib file and it include some reference, such as :

```
@article{Rijnsdorp1998,
booktitle = {ICES J. Mar. Sci.},
doi = {10.1006/jmsc.1997.0326},
issn = {10543139},
keywords = {Beam trawling,Benthos,Ecosystem effects,Effort distribution},
number = {3},
pages = {403--419},
title = {{Micro-scale distribution of beam trawl effort in the southern North Sea between 1993 and 1996 in relation to the trawling frequency of the sea bed and the impact on benthic organisms}},
volume = {55},
year = {1998}
}
```

The question is : the citication in paper is right, the order in Reference is right, such as
the order should be "**Murawski**", "**Rijnsdorp**", "**Stefansson**"(M, R, S). But why these name is inverting? These reference should be "Murawski A. S.    Rijnsdorp A. D.     Stefansson G.".

[image]

**the code is here:**

```
\usepackage[round,authoryear]{natbib}
\begin{document}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{paper_oe}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please provide a sample entry that actually contains an `author` field. Incidentally, why does the entry of the type `@article` feature a field called `booktitle`? Why isn't that field called `journal`?

Comment: You appear to have chosen a bibliographystyle -- `plainnat` -- that is programmed to show authors' full names as `<Full-Given-Name Surname>. If you would rather show authors' names as `<Surname Given-Name-Initials>`, you shouldn't be using `plainnat`. The journal you plan to submit your paper to probably provides some guidance as to which bibliography style authors ought to employ.

Comment: you are asking about author formatting but haven't posted a useable example and the one bib entry that you have posted has no author field at all so does not appear to be related to the question.

Comment: Thanks for above comments. I have solved this problem, the artical "Ocean Engineering" provide a bibliography style called (\bibliographystyle{cas-model2-names}), and I missed it and comment this code carefullness. So thanks all above.